# Excel - order of occurrence / running total formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to craft a formula to find which occurrence of a value within a column with multiple values that row represents. Put another way, I'm looking for a running total of the value in the row. I know that the order of occurrence / running total will be arbitrary / will change upon sorting; that's fine. To better explain, here's what I'm looking for:

```
Col A    Col B
(list)   (occurrence)
Lion     1
Tiger    1
Lion     2
Bear     1
Bear     2
Lion     3
Tiger    2
```

Comment: Hello! You should try to add your attempts so far for the matter, that way you can get some feedback

Comment: @sab the answer marked as the answer perfectly answers my question; no further feedback is necessary. However, as a new user, I appreciate your suggestion and will keep it in mind for future questions that I may ask. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNTIF()`.  E.g., in Cell `B7`, try this:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:A7,A7)
```

`=COUNTIF(range, criterion)`

What it's doing is looking in the ***range*** for cells that match the ***criterion***.

Note that `$` makes an "absolute" reference, so the reference to the first cell of your range won't change when you copy/paste it throughout column `B`; it'll always point to the first cell in the range even as the relative references update.

Comment: you're a genius. I'm using COUNTIF and COUNTIFS extensively throughout the rest of the workbook, including in my poor workaround (which relied on a certain sort to work), so I don't know why I didn't think of this. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

This could also be done dynamically using LET:

```
=LET(data,A1:A7,
  COUNTIF(OFFSET(data,,,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(data))),data)
```

Or without using LET:

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1:A7,,,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A1:A7))),A1:A7)
```

But it contains OFFSET which makes it volatile.

For those that have access to `BYROW` (currently in Beta) you could spill the count like this:

```
=BYROW(A1:A7,LAMBDA(myrow,
        COUNTIF(A1 :INDEX(A:A,ROW(myrow)),myrow)))
```

[image]